# Some issues that are bothering me about the following sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-difference

The sentence is:

*Intrigued by its success, I wanted to deepen my knowledge **of** the language’s history and **of** the unique culture that **sprang** around it.*

I wrote it as a part of a project I have to submit, and there are two distinct aspects of this sentence that make me doubt its grammatical correctness:

- Is the use of the word "of" (in bold, in both instances) appropriate here? I'm conflicted between using it and "about".
- According to  Google, the definition of the verb "to spring" is "to originate or arise from", and in my sentence, the unique culture sprang **around** the language and not **from** it. Is the usage here correct?  Should I replace it with "grew" or something like that?

Help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

> Intrigued by its success, I wanted to deepen my knowledge **of** the language’s history and **of** the unique culture that **sprang** around it.

The use of "***of***" certainly does have the meaning "***about***"

> Intrigued by its success, I wanted to deepen my knowledge **about** the language’s history and **about** the unique culture that sprang around it.

Though it may be better to use

> Intrigued by its success, I wanted to deepen my knowledge **about** the language’s history and **of** the unique culture that sprang around it.

to avoid repetition of "***about***".

For your second part, usually the phrase is

> sprung **up**
>
> Intrigued by its success, I wanted to deepen my knowledge **about** the language’s history and **of** the unique culture that **sprung up** around it.

Comment: Thanks! Now when I think of it, can I use "sprouted" instead of "sprung up"?

Comment: Yes, that would be as understandable, but the nuance is "***sprouted***" is less *forceful* than "***sprung up***".

Comment: I find "of" way more natural than 'about', the sentence in the answer sounds awkward to me because of it.